# Retrieve the type of field using Schema classes

Tags: apex, schema, describesobject, sobjecttype, sobjectfield

I am trying to create a generic class to retrieve the type of a field for any sObject.

I am struggling with the following part of the code:

```
String[] fields = ['Id','Name'];   
for(sObject o : newRecordsFromTrigger){  
       for(String fieldName : fields ){
          // Need a generic method to get output as below
          // System.debug('field type +++'+Account.Id.getDescribe().getType());
          // above will work fine, but I want a generic method something as below.
          // System.debug('field type +++'+o.fieldName.getDescribe().getType());
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two key points here:

- get dynamically `SObjectType` from `SObject` by calling `getSObjectType()`
- get map of fields by calling `fields.getMap()`

---

```
List<String> fields = new List<String>{'Name'};
SObject acct = new Account(Name = 'Test');

Map<String, SObjectField> fieldsMap = acct.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for(String field :fields){
    Schema.DisplayType displayType = fieldsMap.get(field).getDescribe().getType();
    System.debug('displayType: '+ displayType);
}
```

---

The result is:

> displayType: STRING

---

you can also use singleton pattern or static class variables in order to optimize code and store across transaction previously checked sobjects and fields in a map.

Comment: Thanks. it worked